# Why does LinkedList not expose its Node class?

Tags: java, data-structures, encapsulation, doubly-linked-list

If I develop the linked list from scratch, I can store a pointer to a Node object inside my business entity class and achieve constant O(1) **remove** and **insertAfter** operations. In the java standard library implementation, they are O(n) which can differ tremendously when processing large data sets.

Why don't they just made the Node class public and encapsulated some details inside it still making the class itself (via interface maybe) accessable? It would make LinkedList more flexible.

Do we have something like **FlexibleLinkedList** in Apache Commons or Guava?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### `ListIterator`

> Why don't they just made the Node class public and encapsulated some details inside it still making the class itself (via interface maybe) accessable?

There is no need to.

> Why don't they just made the Node class public and encapsulated some details inside it still making the class itself (via interface maybe) accessable? It would make LinkedList more flexible.

That already exists.

If you want to have the benefits of node-based operations, like:

- Give me the next item, based on current node
- Delete the node I already have, without locating it
- Insert something after my node that I already have

you just have to use a `ListIterator` as returned by [list.listIterator()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#listIterator()). This method is offered by all `List`s.

This class encapsulates the logic of knowing the current node in an iteration and offers efficient methods for manipulation that directly use the `Node`s, such as:

- `add` - The element is inserted immediately before the element that would be returned by `next()`
- `set` - Replaces the last element returned by `next()` or `previous()` with the specified element
- `remove` - Removes from the list the last element that was returned by `next()` or `previous()`

While offering methods to control the iteration with `next()` and `previous()`.

---

### Example

So you could for example change every second element:

```
LinkedList<Integer> values = new LinkedList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));

int i = 0;
ListIterator<Integer> iter = values.listIterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    iter.next();

    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        iter.set(100);
    }

    i++;
}
```

Resulting in

```
[100, 2, 100, 4, 100, 6, 100, 8, 100, 10]
```

And this code runs in `O(n)`, it does **not** need to re-locate the nodes each time. In contrast to the bad equivalent of

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        list.set(i, 100);
    }
}
```

which runs in `O(n^2)` for the reasons you have stated.

---

### Benefits of hiding `Node`

In general, it is much better to encapsulate and hide your private inner workings. An user should not bother how `LinkedList` does its job behind the curtain.

Also, if it would expose the `Node`, an user could sneakily edit them and the whole list goes bonkers.

For example an user *could* then do

```
Node a = list.getNodeAtIndex(3);   
Node b = a.next;
Node c = b.next;

// Remove b
a.next = c;
c.previous = a;
```

Without also adjusting the `size` of the list. So `list.size()` would return a wrong number now, probably leading to crashes during iterations.

Or you could also introduce a dangerous loop:

```
a.next = b;
b.next = a;
```

Or forget to set `previous`, resulting in a *different list* when iterated backwards:

```
a.next = c;
c.previous = b;
```

---

`ListIterator` ensures that such stuff can not happen, while offerring the same functionality. So instead of exposing the nodes directly to the user, it exposes only the desired functionality, in form of methods for which it has full control over.

Comment: What if I want to remove all nodes from a specified index to the end. This should be a constant time operation given the node to remove from. I can't find a way to do this.

Comment: @febot Right, but the use case for this is probably extremely niche. So niche that it likely justifies rolling your own solution anyways. Also, note that you can do `subList(0, thatIndex)` to get a list that would behave the same. And that there is also `ArrayDeque` in case you are looking for a queue instead (popping multiple elements at the end sounds more like a queue-task)